# maximum variation within one second for each row of a DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm having a calculation problem with pandas and I'd like to know if anyone could help me.

Having this df created using this code:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'B': [0, 2, 1, np.nan, 4, 1, 3, 10, np.nan, 3, 6]},
                  index = [pd.Timestamp('20130101 09:31:23.999'),
                           pd.Timestamp('20130101 09:31:24.200'),
                           pd.Timestamp('20130101 09:31:24.250'),
                           pd.Timestamp('20130101 09:31:25.000'),
                           pd.Timestamp('20130101 09:31:25.375'),
                           pd.Timestamp('20130101 09:31:25.850'),
                           pd.Timestamp('20130101 09:31:26.100'),
                           pd.Timestamp('20130101 09:31:27.150'),
                           pd.Timestamp('20130101 09:31:28.050'),
                           pd.Timestamp('20130101 09:31:28.850'),
                           pd.Timestamp('20130101 09:31:29.200')])
```

```
df

|                         | B    |
|-------------------------|------|
| 2013-01-01 09:31:23.999 | 0.0  |
| 2013-01-01 09:31:24.200 | 2.0  |
| 2013-01-01 09:31:24.250 | 1.0  |
| 2013-01-01 09:31:25.000 | NaN  |
| 2013-01-01 09:31:25.375 | 4.0  |
| 2013-01-01 09:31:25.850 | 1.0  |
| 2013-01-01 09:31:26.100 | 3.0  |
| 2013-01-01 09:31:27.150 | 10.0 |
| 2013-01-01 09:31:28.050 | NaN  |
| 2013-01-01 09:31:28.850 | 3.0  |
| 2013-01-01 09:31:29.200 | 6.0  |
```

I would like to be able to calculate for each row what the maximum variation of B has been during one second.

For example, in the first row you would have to look at how much it has changed with respect to the second row and the third row which are those within the interval of a second and calculate the difference with the maximum value.

In this case, the maximum value is in the second row "09:31:24.200", the maximum variation will be 2 - 0.

Then, we will create a new column with all these maximum variations for each of the rows.

```
df

|                         | B    | Maximum Variation  |
|-------------------------|------|--------------------|
| 2013-01-01 09:31:23.999 | 0.0  | 2.0                |
| 2013-01-01 09:31:24.200 | 2.0  | 1.0                |
| 2013-01-01 09:31:24.250 | 1.0  | 0.0                |
| 2013-01-01 09:31:25.000 | NaN  | 4.0                |
| 2013-01-01 09:31:25.375 | 4.0  |-3.0                |
| 2013-01-01 09:31:25.850 | 1.0  | 2.0                |
| 2013-01-01 09:31:26.100 | 3.0  | 0.0                |
| 2013-01-01 09:31:27.150 | 10.0 | 0.0                |
| 2013-01-01 09:31:28.050 | NaN  | 3.0                |
| 2013-01-01 09:31:28.850 | 3.0  | 3.0                |
| 2013-01-01 09:31:29.200 | 6.0  | 0.0                |
```

I hope it's clear enough

**Solution has been found and shared in the answers, but still an efficiency improvement in this solution that doesn't involve having to make a loop for each row of the df, will be more than welcome**

Comment: why is the max variant for  `2013-01-01 09:31:24.250` 0 and not -1? There is only one value within 1second of it and that is `2013-01-01 09:31:25.000` which has a `B` of nan Assuming nans are zero the difference would be -1

Comment: Do you want the max difference for each second interval here, like the 2 09:31:24 values?, Or are you interested in time deltas, so 1 (or 0.5) second(s) from 09:31:24.250?

Comment: in case, that we have nan value, we do not consider it as a zero, we consider that there is no value to compare

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've finally found the solution:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'B': [0, 1, 2, 8, 6, 1, 3, 10, np.nan, 3, 6]},
                  index = [pd.Timestamp('20130101 09:31:23.999'),
                           pd.Timestamp('20130101 09:31:24.200'),
                           pd.Timestamp('20130101 09:31:24.250'),
                           pd.Timestamp('20130101 09:31:25.000'),
                           pd.Timestamp('20130101 09:31:25.375'),
                           pd.Timestamp('20130101 09:31:25.850'),
                           pd.Timestamp('20130101 09:31:26.100'),
                           pd.Timestamp('20130101 09:31:27.150'),
                           pd.Timestamp('20130101 09:31:28.050'),
                           pd.Timestamp('20130101 09:31:28.850'),
                           pd.Timestamp('20130101 09:31:29.200')])

df = df.reset_index()

df = df.rename(columns={"index": "start_date"})

df['duration_in_seconds'] = 1

df['end_date'] = df['start_date'] + pd.to_timedelta(df['duration_in_seconds'], unit='s')

df['max'] = np.nan

for index, row in df.iterrows():
    start = row['start_date']
    end = row['end_date']
    maxi = df[(df['start_date'] >= start ) & (df['start_date'] <= end)]['B'].max()
    df.iloc[index, df.columns.get_loc('max')] = maxi

df['Maximum Variation'] = df['max'] - df['B']

df

|    | start_date              | B    | duration_in_seconds | end_date                | max  | Maximum Variation |
|----|-------------------------|------|---------------------|-------------------------|------|-------------------|
| 0  | 2013-01-01 09:31:23.999 | 0.0  | 1                   | 2013-01-01 09:31:24.999 | 2.0  | 2.0               |
| 1  | 2013-01-01 09:31:24.200 | 1.0  | 1                   | 2013-01-01 09:31:25.200 | 8.0  | 7.0               |
| 2  | 2013-01-01 09:31:24.250 | 2.0  | 1                   | 2013-01-01 09:31:25.250 | 8.0  | 6.0               |
| 3  | 2013-01-01 09:31:25.000 | 8.0  | 1                   | 2013-01-01 09:31:26.000 | 8.0  | 0.0               |
| 4  | 2013-01-01 09:31:25.375 | 6.0  | 1                   | 2013-01-01 09:31:26.375 | 6.0  | 0.0               |
| 5  | 2013-01-01 09:31:25.850 | 1.0  | 1                   | 2013-01-01 09:31:26.850 | 3.0  | 2.0               |
| 6  | 2013-01-01 09:31:26.100 | 3.0  | 1                   | 2013-01-01 09:31:27.100 | 3.0  | 0.0               |
| 7  | 2013-01-01 09:31:27.150 | 10.0 | 1                   | 2013-01-01 09:31:28.150 | 10.0 | 0.0               |
| 8  | 2013-01-01 09:31:28.050 | NaN  | 1                   | 2013-01-01 09:31:29.050 | 3.0  | NaN               |
| 9  | 2013-01-01 09:31:28.850 | 3.0  | 1                   | 2013-01-01 09:31:29.850 | 6.0  | 3.0               |
| 10 | 2013-01-01 09:31:29.200 | 6.0  | 1                   | 2013-01-01 09:31:30.200 | 6.0  | 0.0               |
```

More time efficient solutions are still welcome

Answer (score 0):

More efficient solution

```
df = df.reset_index()

df = df.rename(columns={"index": "start_date"})

df['duration_in_seconds'] = 1

df['end_date'] = df['start_date'] + pd.to_timedelta(df['duration_in_seconds'], unit='s')

df['max'] = np.nan

df["max"] = df.apply(lambda row : df.loc[(df["start_date"] >= row['start_date']) & (df["start_date"] <=row['end_date'])]["B"].max(), axis = 1)

df['Maximum Variation'] = df['max'] - df['B']
```

Answer (score -1):

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'B': [0, 2, 1, np.nan, 4, 1, 3, 10, np.nan, 3, 6]},
                  index = [pd.Timestamp('20130101 09:31:23.999'),
                           pd.Timestamp('20130101 09:31:24.200'),
                           pd.Timestamp('20130101 09:31:24.250'),
                           pd.Timestamp('20130101 09:31:25.000'),
                           pd.Timestamp('20130101 09:31:25.375'),
                           pd.Timestamp('20130101 09:31:25.850'),
                           pd.Timestamp('20130101 09:31:26.100'),
                           pd.Timestamp('20130101 09:31:27.150'),
                           pd.Timestamp('20130101 09:31:28.050'),
                           pd.Timestamp('20130101 09:31:28.850'),
                           pd.Timestamp('20130101 09:31:29.200')])

print(df)

    B
2013-01-01 09:31:23.999 0.0
2013-01-01 09:31:24.200 2.0
2013-01-01 09:31:24.250 1.0
2013-01-01 09:31:25.000 NaN
2013-01-01 09:31:25.375 4.0
2013-01-01 09:31:25.850 1.0
2013-01-01 09:31:26.100 3.0
2013-01-01 09:31:27.150 10.0
2013-01-01 09:31:28.050 NaN
2013-01-01 09:31:28.850 3.0
2013-01-01 09:31:29.200 6.0

df_min = df.resample('1S').min()
print(df_min)

    B
2013-01-01 09:31:23 0.0
2013-01-01 09:31:24 1.0
2013-01-01 09:31:25 1.0
2013-01-01 09:31:26 3.0
2013-01-01 09:31:27 10.0
2013-01-01 09:31:28 3.0
2013-01-01 09:31:29 6.0

df_max = df.resample('1S').max()
print(df_max)

    B
2013-01-01 09:31:23 0.0
2013-01-01 09:31:24 2.0
2013-01-01 09:31:25 4.0
2013-01-01 09:31:26 3.0
2013-01-01 09:31:27 10.0
2013-01-01 09:31:28 3.0
2013-01-01 09:31:29 6.0


df_diff = df_max - df_min

print(df_diff)

    B
2013-01-01 09:31:23 0.0
2013-01-01 09:31:24 1.0
2013-01-01 09:31:25 3.0
2013-01-01 09:31:26 0.0
2013-01-01 09:31:27 0.0
2013-01-01 09:31:28 0.0
2013-01-01 09:31:29 0.0
```

Comment: What it will happen if we have a value of 1 in the second 24.600 and a value of 5 in the second 25.200. With your solution we're not calculating this difference.  we need to calculate for each row its maximum difference for a full second for that row. Then for this row, we would need to consider the maximum difference between the first value in the second 24.600 and the maximum value up to the second 25.600